# Reverse a 32-bitstring in C

Tags: c, reverse, bit-fields

Edit: looks like the main issue was with the expected test cases given, rather than my solution. Hopefully, this will be useful to other people that need a quick way to reverse the bit-order of words in C.

Note: This Q has been downvoted (presumably because people feel that the question wasn't technically correct, as if every question here is going to know the exact issue before asking -- even though, had I known that the supplied expected results are misleading, I wouldn't have needed to ask for help in the first place...).

I'm having trouble writing a simple C-function to reverse a uint32 bitwise.

Below is the test code along with the expected results:

```
printf("\nReverse(0xDEADBEEF) = 0x%X\n", Reverse(0xDEADBEEFU)); // should be 0xf77db57b
printf("Reverse(0x12345678) = 0x%X\n", Reverse(0x12345678U));   // should be 0x3cd4589
printf("Reverse(0) = 0x%X\n", Reverse(0));                      // should be 0
printf("Reverse(0xFFFFFFFF) = 0x%X\n", Reverse(0xFFFFFFFFU));   // should be 0xFFFFFFFFU
```

But when I run my program, I get the following output:

```
Reverse(0xDEADBEEF) = 0xF77DB57B
Reverse(0x12345678) = 0x1E6A2C48
Reverse(0) = 0x0
Reverse(0xFFFFFFFF) = 0xFFFFFFFF
```

So something is wrong with the 0x12345678U case. Notice that the solution is off by a factor of two (only in that case, the 0xDEADBEEFU and 0 and 0xFFFFFFFF cases are fine).

Finally, the Reverse function is below:

```
uint32_t Reverse(const uint32_t Input)
{
    uint32_t Out = 0U;
    uint32_t Indx;
    uint32_t N = Input;
    for (Indx = 0U; Indx <= 31U; Indx++)
    {
        Out |= (N & 1U) << (31U - Indx);
        N >>= 1U;
    }
    return Out;
};
```

So I'm stumped on what's causing the issue.

Any tips or ideas, please?

Comment: First of all split up complex expressions into simpler ones, saving the result in variables. Then use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement, monitoring variables and their values. By breaking up the complex expressions into their simplest parts, you can very easily see when one of the calculations are wrong.

Comment: Your answer is good when you reverse all 32 bits, but the expected answer seems to skip leading zero bits, so you'll have to find out how many bits to reverse, in that case only 29 bits, I think.

Comment: `Reverse(0x12345678U));   // should be 0x3cd4589` wut? Is't your code right? How should `0x...8` result in `0x3..`? Should be `0x1...`, the `0x1E6A2C48` is ok.

Comment: That's a good point @MOehm, I'll chase up that thought!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the expected output, you need to skip leading `0`:s.
One way would be to shift down the value by `1` each loop and then check if the value is still non-zero.

Example:

```c
uint32_t Reverse(uint32_t Input) {
    uint32_t Output = 0;

    while(Input) {    // non-zero?
        Output <<= 1;
        Output |= Input & 1;
        Input >>= 1;
    }
    return Output;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/edrz3TGjh)